# Is there a way to read data from smart contract using PHP?

Tags: go-ethereum, php

I have a smart contract. All what I need is to make a PHP script that will get some public data from smart contract using it's address. How can I do that? Maybe there is some libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. I don't know if there are PHP libraries available, but as long as you can make an HTTP request and deal with JSON, this is pretty easy to do. See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call.

You can send such a JSON-RPC call to any Ethereum node. [Infura](https://infura.io) is a public node that you could use.

Comment: Ok. But how I can get data from mapping in the contract? How I need to send JSON request?

Comment: Give https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php a try. Specifically, `$contract->at($contractAddress)->call($functionName, $params, $callback);`.

Comment: You could use a library like [Ethereum-PHP](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) which is [documented](http://ethereum-php.org/dev/).

Comment: @digitaldonkey Documentation site seems to be down?

Comment: Just migrated ethereum-php.org yesterday. Should be online again.